# Problems moving a web link on the desktop

Tags: firefox

I am having this annoying problem that my web links that I have dragged from Firefox can not be moved afterwards. When I try, I just get a copy of the link as a file.

I don't know if the problem is caused by bad settings on Firefox or on Ubuntu. But what I see is that the property of the web file states: filesize, access or modification is unknown. The permission could not be determined.

I have Ubuntu version 14, but 13 had the same problem. The "Desktop" dir has all the read/write rights set and the web link has the same! chmod 777 on the web link did not do anything good.

I hope you can help me with some of you magic.

Thanks. 
Henrik.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in Nautilus, see [bug #1278437](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1278437).

As far as I know there's no magic spell for that :-(

Comment: Avoid thanks! I will still say thanks for the info. I will from now on take a look at bug reports when I have problems with Ubuntu.